# ANTLR4 String and Comments Lexer

Tags: string, comments, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm new to ANTLR so I hope you guy explains for me explicitly.

I have a /* comment */ (BC) lexer in ANTLR, I want it to be like this:

```
/* sample */ => BC
/* s
a
m
p
l
e */ => BC
"" => STRING
" " => STRING
"a" => STRING
"hello world \1" => STRING
```

but I got this:

```
/* sample */
/* s
a
m
p
l
e */ => BC
""
" "
"a"
"hello world \1" => STRING
```

it only take the 1st /* and the last */, same with my String token. Here's the code of Comments:

```
BC: '/*'.*'*/';
```

And the String:

```
STRING: '"'(~('"')|(' '|'\b'|'\f'|'r'|'\n'|'\t'|'\"'|'\\'))*'"';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lexer rules are **greedy** by default, meaning they try to consume the longest matching sequence. So they stop at the last closing delimiter.

To make a rule non-greedy, use, well, nongreedy rules:

```
BC: '/*' .*? '*/';
```

This will stop at the *first* closing `*/` which is exactly what you need.

Same with your STRING. Read about it in *The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference*, page 285.

Comment: Thank you for the Comments' solution. But in String, if I use `?` then everything was fine until I test this testcase: `"He asked me: \"Where is John?\""` . It will return the phrase `"He asked me:\" => STRING`. But I want to have the whole sentence. This is my Lexer: `STRING: '"' (~('"')|(' '|'\b'|'\f'|'r'|'\n'|'\t'|'\"'|'\\'))*?'"';` I think I've included the \" as a legit content in STRING, but it's not work.

Comment: This is my String requirement from the assignment: String literals consist zero or more characters enclosed by double quotes ("). Use escape
sequences (listed below) to represent special characters within a string.
It is a compile-time error for a new line or EOF character to appear inside a string literal.
All the supported escape sequences are as follows: \b \f \r \n \t \" \\

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the following code fragment without non-greedy syntax (more general soultion):

```
MultilineCommentStart:        '/*' -> more, mode(COMMENTS);

mode COMMENTS;

MultilineComment:             '*/' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
MultilineCommentNotAsterisk: ~'*'+ -> more;
MultilineCommentAsterisk:     '*'  -> more;
```